# "Pulled the rope" vs "pulled at the rope."

Tags: grammar

What's the difference? Example:

> I pulled the rope to make sure it was secure.
>
> I pulled at the rope to make sure it was secure.

Comment: The phrase "*pulled at*" describes a series of small, light tugs, as one might do after throwing a grapnel, for example; straight "*pull*" indicates continuous, and usually maximal, effort (*maximal* in the sense of "sufficient to move the object at the other end of the rope, or as hard as I can, whichever is lesser").

Comment: @DanBron - Do you not want to post that as an answer? It sounds good to me.

Comment: @medica But *mooooom* writing an actual *answer* with references and justification and **everything** is so much *woooorkkkk*.  No thank you. Let someone else roll around on a bed covered with imaginary internet points.

Comment: Some day, @Dan Bron, you may be able to cash these points in for imaginary money, BitCoins or MilliCents, or some'pin.

Comment: They're good for miles on Braniff Airlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are so fun, and already getting upvoted (mutual admiration society?).  Anyway, if the rope was actually already secure, you could say "pulled at", but more likely you'd say "tugged on".  This doesn't necessarily involve moving the rope at all.  (by the way, "pulled at" sounds particularly ineffectual, like "pawed at".) However If the rope was not already secure, the person could "pull" the rope, or "pull on" the rope, to tighten it so that it was secure. He could do both: "...pulled the rope into a knot, then tugged on it to make sure it was secure"