# Pull on/at (heave on/at)

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

> Harry heaved on the rope.

MY RESEARCH: "heave on" means "pull on" --
What is the difference between:
Pull a rope, pull on a rope, pull at a rope?

Comment: It is not about the word but the preposition.

Comment: An aside: *heave* suggests a substantial physical effort, while *pull* is a bit vaguer about how much Harry is sweating at the task.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221491/pulled-the-rope-vs-pulled-at-the-rope?rq=1). _Pull on_ suggests to me a continuous pulling action.